# CSS rules that slow down the browser speed (rendering)

Tags: css, optimization

I'm searching for the biggest mistakes that you can make in your CSS code; CSS rules that slow down the browser speed (rendering).

For example:

```
.myDraggables {
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #000 inset; 
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #000 inset; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #000 inset;

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#cdcdcd, endColorstr=#fff);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#cdcdcd), to(#fff));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #cdcdcd,  #fff);

    border-radius:5px 7px 1px 3px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px 7px 1px 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px 7px 1px 3px;
}
```

If you have 10 draggable elements (many tags inside) with this class, the drag would be very slow (jerk).
So, does anybody know a list of CSS rules that you shouldn't use?

Comment: It's often a combination of styles. In this case, the combination of gradient, rounded corners, dragging and having many of them.

Comment: It also depends on the browser. IE8 has some strengths over FF and vice-versa, and Chrome really seems to handle everything well.

Comment: hope this older answer can help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486017/css3-what-are-the-performance-best-practices/7488014#7488014

Comment: I experienced, that the fixed background image can also slow the rendering while scrolling.

Answer (score 3):

One that's easy to make: using a tiny image (lets say 5x5) as a background repeat for big areas is slow when it comes to rendering. So it's advisable to use a bigger picture for repeat patterns (eg. 50x50). The size of a file increases just a bit, but the performance is way better.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid long paths i.e.

```
body div div ul li span a {}
```

Avoid css expressions i.e.

```
background-color: expression( (new Date()).getHours()%2 ? "#B8D4FF" : "#F08A00" );
```

And anything that microsoft implemented i.e. DX etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning overflow settings to the elements slows the scrolling in mobile browsers

Comment: Can you cite some supporting literature?