# CSS Transition doesn't work with top, bottom, left, right

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I have an element with style

```
position: relative;
transition: all 2s ease 0s;
```

Then I want to change its position smoothly after clicking on it, but when I add the style change the transition doesn't take place, instead, the element moves instantly.

```
$$('.omre')[0].on('click',function(){
    $$(this).style({top:'200px'});
});
```

However, if I change the `color` property, for example, it changes smoothly.

```
$$('.omre')[0].on('click',function(){
    $$(this).style({color:'red'});
});
```

What might be the cause of this? Are there properties that aren't 'transitional'?

**EDIT**: I guess I should have mentioned that this is not jQuery, it's another library. The code appears to work as intended, styles are being added, but transition only works in the second case?

Comment: Assuming $$ is an alias for jQuery, doing [0] will return a native dom object (as opposed to a jquery object) and not have any `.on()` method. If not - what is $$?

Comment: None of that is valid, if you're using jQuery there's nothing called style(), and in native JS, it surely doesn't work like that.

Comment: There is a set of rules that are transition-able. see [W3 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-css3-transitions-20131119/#properties-from-css-)

Comment: @Goldentoa11 `top` appears to be in the list, which eliminates my doubt about `top` not being available for transitions.

Comment: @php_nub_qq Check adaneo's answer and my comment to it, by the looks of it you need to start out with a `top` value set (to 0 for instance) before you change it (to 200 or whatever)

Comment: Yeah, I saw that too. I was just posting that in the comments since you had asked if there was a list of some sort, but seemed an answer was overkill.

Comment: @xec Thanks to your fiddle I figured out the problem. It was because in my css I wasn't setting `top` to `0`, I was just assuming that it wouldn't matter. After initializing `top:0` the transition now works! You can post that as an answer, because it's mostly your credit! `:P`

Comment: Try this `$(this).animate({top: 200});`  and `$(this).animate({backgroundColor: 'red'});`

Answer (score 266, accepted):

Try setting a default value for `top` in the CSS to let it know where you want it to start out before transitioning:

#### CSS

```
position: relative;
transition: top 2s ease 0s; /* only transition top property */
top: 0; /* start transitioning from position '0' instead of 'auto' */
```

The reason this is needed is because you can't transition from a keyword, and [the default value for `top` is `auto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top#formal_definition).

It is also good practice to [specify exactly what you want to transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-property) (only `top` instead of `all`) both for [performance reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947441) and so you don't transition something else (like `color`) unintentionally.

Comment: or `transition: top 1s ease 0s;` for `top` only

Comment: note: this happens becasue default top value is `auto` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top

Comment: Good point! I have fleshed out the answer a bit since it's still getting attention 8 years later :)

Answer (score 20):

Perhaps you need to specify a top value in your css rule set, so that it will know what value to animate *from*.

Answer (score 3):

In my case div position was fixed , adding left position was not enough it started working only after adding display block

`left:0;
 display:block;`

Answer (score 3):

Something that is not relevant for the OP, but maybe for someone else in the future:

For pixels (`px`), if the value is "0", the unit can be omitted: `right: 0` and `right: 0px` both work.

However I noticed that in Firefox and Chrome this is *not* the case for the seconds unit (`s`). While `transition: right 1s ease 0s` works, `transition: right 1s ease 0` (missing unit `s` for last value `transition-delay`) does **not** (it *does* work in Edge however).

In the following example, you'll see that `right` works for both `0px` and `0`, but `transition` only works for `0s` and it doesn't work with `0`.

```css
#box {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 240px;
    width: 260px;
    margin: 50px;
    position: relative;
}
.jump {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
}
#jump1 {
    background-color: maroon;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    transition: right 1s ease 0s;
}
#jump2 {
    background-color: green;
    top: 60px;
    right: 0;
    transition: right 1s ease 0s;
}
#jump3 {
    background-color: blue;
    top: 120px;
    right: 0px;
    transition: right 1s ease 0;
}
#jump4 {
    background-color: gray;
    top: 180px;
    right: 0;
    transition: right 1s ease 0;
}
#box:hover .jump {
    right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div class="jump" id="jump1">right: 0px<br>transition: right 1s ease 0s</div>
  <div class="jump" id="jump2">right: 0<br>transition: right 1s ease 0s</div>
  <div class="jump" id="jump3">right: 0px<br>transition: right 1s ease 0</div>
  <div class="jump" id="jump4">right: 0<br>transition: right 1s ease 0</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

> *Are there properties that aren't 'transitional'?*

Answer: **Yes**.

If the property is not listed [here](https://www.quackit.com/css/css3/animations/animatable_properties/) it is not *'transitional'*.

Reference: [Animatable CSS Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions#which_css_properties_can_be_transitioned)

Answer (score 1):

### Under the hood while animation

Modern web browsers heavily optimize animations and transitions by using hardware acceleration. This means that animations and transitions are often delegated to the GPU (Graphics Processing Unit) for smoother rendering.

### Concern

You should avoid using transitions with the `left`/`top`/`right`/`bottom` properties.  it can result in flickering/slow or janky animations.

Those don’t create a fluid animation because they have the browser creating layouts each time, which will affect all of their children. it often triggers a "reflow" and a "repaint" of the entire page. Also, they aren't always hardware-accelerated, leading to slower and less smooth animations.

### Solution

Use CSS transitions and animations with properties like **`transform`** and **`opacity`** when you animate as they have no impact on the flow and are much smoother. They are hardware-accelerated in most cases.

### Pro-tip : `will-change`

The `will-change` CSS property is used to provide a hint to the browser about which properties are likely to change and be animated in the future. This hint allows the browser to optimize the rendering of these properties, resulting in better animation performance.

In many cases, when you apply `will-change` to an element, the browser will promote that element to its own GPU-accelerated layer. This means that the element and the specified property are rendered separately from the rest of the page, which can improve rendering performance.

**Warning**: `will-change` is intended to be used as a last resort, in order to try to deal with existing performance problems. It should not be used to anticipate performance problems.