# Using transition:all when only transitioning one property

Tags: css, performance, css-transitions

Say I want to transition *one property*

Are there any issues transitioning with `all` instead of that particular property?

For example say I want to transition `left`.

Are there issues with using something like `transition: all 0.3s;`

instead of `transition: left 0.3s;`

I know that both work, I'm just wondering if there are issues like a performance hit or ...?

The reason I'd rather use `all`, is because I'm supporting right-to-left (rtl) languages as well so if I use

`transition: left 0.3s;` - I'll have to override that in the rtl code with `transition: right 0.3s;`

so if there are no (performance) issues with `all` - I'd prefer that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947441/css3-transitions-is-transition-all-slower-than-transition-x), `transition: all` is in fact slower.

Would `transition: left 0.3s, right 0.3s;` not do the job?