# JQuery hover function opacity animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tumblr-themes

trying to animate a `divs` `opacity` when hovering some other element. First I tried it with `display` `none`/`block`, but it read somewhere it's impossible to make a transition for that.

This is a little complicated, because this is supposed to work on each element of the same type with a different id the same. (Picture gallery with a caption to appear on the bottom of the `img` element when the picture is hovered.)

The HTML structure is like this:

```
<article id="{PostID}">
    <div class="post-content">
        <a><img></a>
        <div class="post-content--padded">
            <p>Caption of the picture.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

First I went with a `mouseover`, `mouseout` approach added to the `post-content` `div` which looked like this:

```
onmouseover="document.getElementById('{PostID}').getElementsByClassName('post-content--padded')[0].style.opacity='1.0';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('{PostID}').getElementsByClassName('post-content--padded')[0].style.opacity='0.0';"
```

That worked, but there was no `transition`. I've set the CSS up with transition handlers to apply to all the css changes within `post-content--padded` like so:

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s;
transition: all 0.3s;
```

This doesn't seem to affect the `mouseover`, `mouseout` opacity change I do, so I tried adding `.animate()` to that, without much success. Well I got `post-content` to fade in and out, but not `post-content--padded`

**Different approach**

That all didn't work so much. So I tried using the `JQuery` function `hover()`.
Long story short I added this above the html in question:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#{PostID}.post-content').hover(
    function(){ $('#{PostID}.post-content.post-content--padded').stop().animate({'opacity': '1'}, 'slow');},
    function(){ $('#{PostID}.post-content.post-content--padded').stop().animate({'opacity': '0'}, 'slow');}
    );
 });
</script>
```

This just doesn't want to work though. Endless browsing of `stackoverflow` and other sources didn't seem to help me with this. Being stuck on this for over an hour I decided to simply ask. It cannot be that hard to add a hover > opactiy transition.

Hope I've not been clear and people understand my issue here.

Comment: you need to display caption of image when hover

Comment: The caption is in `post-content--padded`

Comment: The jQuery approach doesn't work because Tumblr doesn't parse through <script> tags to replace the handlebar'd object ({PostID})

Comment: Aaaah! That must be it then. Well I'm not replacing anything.. --"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it just using css if you need only on hover

```
.post-content--padded{
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s;
    -moz-transition: all 2s;
    transition: all 2s;
}
.post-content:hover .post-content--padded{
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s;
    -moz-transition: all 2s;
    transition: all 2s;
}
```

see demo [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/b5pyqfjn/)

and if you want to use Jquery

```
$('.post-content--padded').hide();
$('.post-content').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.post-content--padded').fadeToggle(2000);
});
```

see demo [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/b5pyqfjn/4/)

Comment: Let me try that out. I tried to use css, but it wouldn't work how I wanted it, so going to try this approach now.

Comment: That worked. I'd still like to know why the jquery won't work, but this is much less hassle anyway, so thanks.

Comment: @RomanRutkowski look at this too http://jsfiddle.net/b5pyqfjn/1/ I add max-height in css so try it also .. about jquery there is a few things you should check .. 1) include jquery to your code . 2) check the selectors you will work with so check {PostID} selector and change it with class is better

Comment: Well I've tested this outside of Tumblr now and it works properly, so it really was Tumblr messing things up.

Comment: @RomanRutkowski see the jquery code too .. I updated my answer .. Good Luck :)

Comment: Don't use `transition: _all_ 2s`. Specify the property that the transition should be applied to instead, i.e. `transition: opacity 2s` for [better performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947441/css3-transitions-is-transition-all-slower-than-transition-x).

Answer (score 1):

I also worked on combining hover with animate and it worked like that:

in CSS opacity for "a" = 0

and in jQuery:

```
$("#classy").hover(function(){
      $("#classy").animate({
          opacity:"1"
      },200);
  }, function(){
      $("#classy").animate({
          opacity:"0"
      },200);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jQuery method that works:

HTML

```
<div id='hover-me'>hover over me</div>
<div id='change-me'>I change opacity</div>
```

CSS

```
.hide {
    opacity:0;
}
```

JS

```
$('#hover-me').hover( function() {
    if ($('#change-me').hasClass('hide')) {
        $('#change-me').removeClass('hide', 'slow');
    } else {
        $('#change-me').addClass('hide', 'slow');
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/senju/s1xwmupy/1/)

*This is with jQueryUI included

Comment: This looks like it would work, however I've been informed Tumblr doesn't parse through <script> elements.