# Hover Over Text, Image Fades In & Out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I had some help yesterday with getting an image to fade in when hovering over another link, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get it to fade out. This might involve java? My apologizes, as I am quite new to more advanced coding (past basic CSS/HTML).

Here's what someone gave me yesterday, which fades in nicely, but id like it to fade out once you remove your mouse from the link.

```
img { opacity: 0; }
a:hover +img {
    -webkit-animation: changeOpacity 5s;
    animation: changeOpacity 5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes changeOpacity {
    0%   { opacity: 0; }    
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes changeOpacity {
    0%   { opacity: 0; }    
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<a href="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/sports/1">
    Hover the see Full image,click to go there
</a>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/sports/1" width="200" height="200" />
<br>
<a href="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/sports/1">
    Hover the see Full image,click to go there
</a>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/sports/1" width="200" height="200" />
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keyframes is massive overkill here. You can simply use `transition` and then change the `opacity` value as needed:

```
img { 
    opacity: 0; 
    transition: opacity 5s;
}
a:hover +img {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/u4epe7ne/1/)

Note that I sped up the transition in the Fiddle as 5 seconds is a little excessive for a fade-in effect in my experience.

Comment: Or transition just the `opacity`?

Comment: @Jivings Yep, you could restrict it if needed.

Comment: [Don't use `transition:all` unless it's necessary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947441/css3-transitions-is-transition-all-slower-than-transition-x).

Comment: @Jivings thanks - every day is a school day. Updated.

Comment: Great thank you so much! I'm assuming this code will work if I decide to position the images/text in various places on the page?

Comment: Glad to help. So long as the `img` elements are a sibling of the `a`, yes, it'll work anywhere in the page.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it : (run it directly below)

```js
$('a').hover( function(){
    $(this).parent().find('img').css('opacity',1)
}, function(){
    $(this).parent().find('img').css('opacity',0)
});
```

```css
img{
    opacity : 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <a href="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/sports/1">Hover the see Full image,click to go there</a>        <br>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/sports/1" width="200" height="200" />
</div>
    
<div>   
<a href="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/sports/1">Hover the see Full image,click to go there</a><br>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/sports/1" width="200" height="200" />
</div>
```