# Transition without properties specified

Tags: css, css-animations

I am learning how to make modal images in CSS and came across this example where there are two declaration blocks containing a transition specifying only the duration(?):

```
#myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
```

and

```
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
```

It is written on the chapter '[How to...Modal Images](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp)' . (w3Schools). Is this correct? and if yes, is it a replacement for `transition: all 0.3s;` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the MDN, the initial value for `transition-property` is `all`, so if you don't specify it in the shorthand `transition` it should function the same way.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition

Same thing from the W3: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#the-transition-property-property-

Answer (score 5):

Like Sean said the initial value for `transition` is all. This does not mean you should use it like that though. It is known that using the initial value could cause drawbacks in performance, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947441/css3-transitions-is-transition-all-slower-than-transition-x).

It is better if you declare each value that you want your transition be applied to. You may not see the performance hit at first, but as you keep extending your CSS file it is something you want to keep an eye on.

Examples:

---

**Without declaring `all` value:**

```css
.shape {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 20px solid;
  border-color: #4285F4 #0F9D58 #F4B400 #DB4437;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in;
}
.shape:hover {
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
<div class="shape"></div>
<div class="shape"></div>
<div class="shape"></div>
<div class="shape"></div>
<div class="shape"></div>
```

---

**Declaring `all` value:**

```css
.shape {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 20px solid;
  border-color: #4285F4 #0F9D58 #F4B400 #DB4437;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}
.shape:hover {
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
<div class="shape"></div>
<div class="shape"></div>
<div class="shape"></div>
<div class="shape"></div>
<div class="shape"></div>
```

---

**Better performance:**

```css
.shape {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 20px solid;
  border-color: #4285F4 #0F9D58 #F4B400 #DB4437;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: border-radius 0.5s ease-in, width 0.5s ease-in, height 0.5s ease-in;
}
.shape:hover {
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
<div class="shape"></div>
<div class="shape"></div>
<div class="shape"></div>
<div class="shape"></div>
<div class="shape"></div>
```

---

**Even better Perfomance**

*If you can afford the element overlap and the `border-width` increment to avoid redraw.*

```css
.shape {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 20px solid;
  border-color: #4285F4 #0F9D58 #F4B400 #DB4437;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: border-radius 0.5s ease-in, transform 0.5s ease-in;
  transform-origin: top left;
}
.shape:hover {
  border-radius: 0;
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
<div class="shape"></div>
<div class="shape"></div>
<div class="shape"></div>
<div class="shape"></div>
<div class="shape"></div>
```

---

Read [this](http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2014/03/18/css-animations-and-transitions-performance/) for further explanation.