# What the dot before a value means in CSS?

Tags: css

I was looking at the Angular 2 tutorial and this detail in the CSS caught my attention.

What does the dot in ".1em" means or do?

```
.heroes li:hover {
    color: #607D8B;
    background-color: #DDD;
    left: .1em;
  }
```

Comment: 0.1 em? It's a float value.

Comment: It's just a number, the same as `0.1em`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's short-hand for `0.1em`, ie. one tenth of an em. In other words, you are not limited to whole numbers (integers).

This isn't quite as useless as it seems. CSS minimizers are becoming common and would reduce this code to

```
.heroes li:hover {color:#607D8B;background-color:#DDD;left:.1em;}
```

The leading zero before .1 is just another byte that can go away.

Comment: @Luke Briggs: Why? The question is quite clearly not about the class selector. It even says "value" in the title.

Comment: Specifically: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-3/#font-relative-lengths

Comment: @BoltClock A CSS newbie asking this kind of question probably doesn't know the difference between a selector and a value. Considering how short this answer is, it seems worthwhile to add e.g. "`.heroes` is a [class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors)"

Comment: @Luke Briggs: OK, that's a fair point. I just thought mentioning the class selector with no context seemed out of place.

Answer (score 0):

it mean 0.1em but some people wrote it like .1em, it is short cut, like you used in Maths.

Answer (score 0):

EM is a value relative to the font-size of the element.

.1em is 10% of 1em

With no css:
1em == 16px

If the font size changes, 1em = new font-size value.

Answer (score -1):

The dot actually means 0. and CSS put the number after the dot as a decimal of 1. E.g. .1 = 0.1 or .3s = 0.3s

So, the two blocks below act the same:

```
div {
    transition: all .3s;
}

div {
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

Which results 300 milliseconds or 0.3 second.

Comment: The answer in general is correct, but you should nearly never transition "all" and use specific transitions instead, so I consider this as a "bad" example.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947441/css3-transitions-is-transition-all-slower-than-transition-x