# Css transition all Vs specific transition

Tags: performance, css, css-transitions

I used to add a class with `.easeMe` name to my `css` files and then every time I want to fade an element just add this class to it .

```
.easeMe {
    transition:all .7s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition:all .7s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition:all .7s ease-in-out
}
```

But today I was thinking about making better performance , and I thought if we add specific transition for properties it maybe give a better performance like :

```
.easeBorders {
    transition:border .7s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition:border .7s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition:border .7s ease-in-out
}
```

Or about width,opacity ... 
Is it a correct idea ?

Comment: it's more about avoiding unwanted transition than performance

Comment: this post will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947441/css3-transitions-is-transition-all-slower-than-transition-x