# Add transition property by class to existing transition properties

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, css-transitions

is it possible in CSS3 to let a class just add new transition properties to an existing transition instead of replacing the old transition definition?

For example:

```css
.transition-a {
transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
}

.transition-b {
transition: color 0.3s ease-in !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="transition-a transition-b">
</div>
```

would overwrite transition-a instead of adding an additional property to the exisitng transition definition.

It would be nice if it would be possible to compose different classes like mixins resulting in a property like

```css
transition: color 0.3s ease-in, opacity 0.3 ease-in`
```

without the need to explicitly specify a rule for the combination of both classes that would force you to repeat yourself.

**EDIT**: More Details

I currently use the SASS source of Bootstrap and want to apply an  additional transition on Bootstraps `.badge` class. I have an additional class `.fade` containing  the following:

```css
.custom-badge.fade {
transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in !important;
```

It would work fine if it wouldn't overwrite the definitions of Bootstraps `.badge` class transition property. I simply want to add an additional transition property to the exiting color transitions.

Comment: why not using `transition: all 0.3s ease-in !important;` ? it will add more than what you need but will cover your case

Comment: It overwrites the previous durations and interpolation specifications.

Answer (score 0):

It's **not** possible.

But, my workaround in these situation is to break up the short syntax and rewrite just the property that needs to change, so you can preserve the rest.

In this case:

```
.transition-a {
  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-duration: .3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;
}

.transition-b {
  transition-property: opacity, color;
}
```

NB: you can omit !important if .transition-b is declared after .transition-a
NB2: this works great with background images.

Comment: But i don't want to exchange the property. I want to add another property.

Comment: My bad, updating the example putting .transition-b {
  transition-property: opacity, color;
}

Answer (score 0):

If the transitions have the same duration, delay, and easing, you can always fall back on using `transition-property: all`:

```css
.transition-a {
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
}

.transition-b {
  transition-property: all;
}
```

Ostensibly there's a performance hit for using `all` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8962837), for instance), but it's not something I've ever noticed.